# Accessing records with same name but different ID

Tags: php, mysql

I am handling a database table, where I have a quantity field in it. The quantity is manipulated through a form where it is reduced. The record gets inserted in the table with the new value as a new record with new quantity(reduced) and through this table it is being fetched in the next form. Now the issue is that whenever I fetch the quantity the older record(record with original quantity) is fetched where as the record with new quantity should be fetched.

I tried updating the same record with new value but it is not updating.

Here is the code for the same :

```
$haha="SELECT quantity FROM ready_for_delivery WHERE joborderid='".$data['joborderno']."'";

    $haharesult = mysqli_query($link,$haha);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($haharesult)>0)
    {
        $sql1="UPDATE ready_for_delivery SET quantity='".$_POST['rp_qty']."' WHERE joborderid='".$_data['joborderno']."'";
        $sq1result=mysqli_query($link,$sql1);
        //echo "I am here";


    }
    else
    {

    $quantity="INSERT INTO `ready_for_delivery` (`joborderid`,`joborderdetailsid`,`datetime`, `quantity`) VALUES ('".$data['joborderno']."',' ', now(), '".$_POST['rp_qty']."');";


        $res1 = mysqli_query($link,$quantity);
        echo "done";


    }
```

I am checking if there is any data in the table with specified job order no, if yes, update it else insert as a new record. Every time it inserts as new record. Please guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in this line of code:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($haharesult>0))
```

the closing brackets is in the wrong place. Correct way:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($haharesult)>0)
```

Comment: I did change, but it is still inserting a new record.

Comment: well that makes no sense to me. did you check if the variable names are correct? I'm a bit confused by all those edits of yours, maybe you were too ;)

Comment: Yes, I did check all my variables and they are right. The above edited code is correct.

Comment: you might want to edit above mentioned line too so others who want to help dont stumble upon this syntax error and think this is the solution then

Answer (score 0):

Remove ; from your first line, hope this will work .

```
 $haha="SELECT quantity FROM ready_for_delivery WHERE joborderid='".$data['joborderno']."'"; //remove ;
        //echo $haha;
        $haharesult = mysqli_query($link,$haha);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($haharesult>0))
        {
            $sql1="UPDATE ready_for_delivery SET quantity='".$_POST['rp_qty']."' WHERE joborderid='".$_data['joborderno']."'";
            $sq1result=mysqli_query($link,$sql1);
            //echo "I am here";


        }
        else
        {

        $quantity="INSERT INTO `ready_for_delivery` (`joborderid`,`joborderdetailsid`,`datetime`, `quantity`) VALUES ('".$data['joborderno']."',' ', now(), '".$_POST['rp_qty']."');";


            $res1 = mysqli_query($link,$quantity);
            echo "done";


        }
```

Comment: No use sir. Now neither it is updating nor inserting

Comment: Are you sure your $data['joborderno'] value exist in database ? echo this after query ..echo mysqli_num_rows($haharesult);

Comment: It does exist in database, and I echoed the mysqli_num_rows($haharesult), its giving me 0.

Answer (score 0):

In the `mysqli_query` you have `$sql` a query variable while the actual query is in the `$haha` var.

Also, did you check if variable `$data['joborderno']` is not empty?

Comment: As you can see above, I corrected mysqli_query(), and yes the $data['joborderid'] is not empty.

Comment: You call the cell in one place "joborderid" and in another "joborderno" isi it supposed to be that way?

Comment: Sorry, its $data['joborderno'] and not $data['joborderid']